# Sometimes getting a wrong output on calculating average program

Tags: python

When I enter the numbers 0, 3, 3, 4, 2, -1, I get the correct average of 2.4. However, when I enter 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, -99, I'm getting the result 2.6 instead of 3.4. Below is a summary of what the program has to do and the code. Any ideas or tips would be greatly appreciated.

> This program allows each theater patron to enter a value from
>   0 to 4 indicating the number of stars that the patron awards
>   to the Guide's featured movie of the week. The program
>   executes continuously until the theater manager enters a
>   negative number to quit. At the end of the program, the
>   average star rating for the movie is displayed.

```
totalStars = 0  
numPatrons = 0  
averageStars = 0
numStars = 0

while numStars <= -1:
    numStarsString = float(input("Enter rating for featured movie: ")
    numPatrons += 1
    totalStars += numStars

averageStars = totalStars / numPatrons
print("Average Star Value: " + str(averageStars))
```

Edit: Figured out a way to get it working. Thanks, everyone!

```
totalStars = 0 
numPatrons = 0 

numStarsString = input("Enter rating for featured movie: ")
numStars = float(numStarsString)
totalStars += numStars
numPatrons += 1

while numStars >= 0 and numStars <= 4:
    numStarsString = input("Enter rating for featured movie: ")
    numStars = float(numStarsString)
    if numStars <= -1:
        break
    totalStars += numStars
    numPatrons += 1

averageStars = totalStars / numPatrons
```

Comment: `numStars` is never *less than or equal to* -1, so I don't think your `while` loop is executing

Comment: You're not adding your input to the `totalStars` - instead you're adding `numStars` (which never changes from 0)

Comment: Are you sure you copied that correctly?

Comment: The code doesn't work as described. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for the assistance everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided does not run: you're missing a closing bracket on the cast to a float and, because `NumStars` is initialized to zero, your `while` loop never executes - it only runs when `numStars <= -1`. Even with these corrected, you're still going to have problems. `numStars` is never updated - the user's input goes to `numStarsString`.

The fact that it doesn't work makes it pretty well impossible to debug.

The following code does what you want, and incorporates a few Python features/conventions (variables are lowercase with underscores, `.format()`). I would compare it to the code you've actually written and see what the differences are.

```
total_stars = 0  
patrons = 0  
average_stars = 0
stars = 0

while True:
    stars = float(input("Enter rating for featured movie: ")
    if stars < 0:
        break
    patrons += 1
    total_stars += stars

average_stars = total_stars / patrons
print("Average Star Value: {}".format(average_stars))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the while-loop, put the conditional statement inside:

```
while True:
    numStars = float(input("Enter rating for featured movie: "))
    if numStars < 0:
        break
numPatrons += 1
totalStars += numStars
```

Code:

```
totalStars = 0  
numPatrons = 0  
averageStars = 0
numStars = 0

while True:
    numStars = float(input("Enter rating for featured movie: "))
    if numStars < 0:
        break
    numPatrons += 1
    totalStars += numStars
averageStars = totalStars / numPatrons
print("Average Star Value: " + str(averageStars))
```

output:

```
Enter rating for featured movie: 1
Enter rating for featured movie: 2
Enter rating for featured movie: 3
Enter rating for featured movie: 4
Enter rating for featured movie: 4
Enter rating for featured movie: 3
Enter rating for featured movie: 2
Enter rating for featured movie: 1
Enter rating for featured movie: -99
Average Star Value: 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

`while` is an entry-controlled loop i.e. once the condition is satisfied, the body of the loop gets executed. Here `numStars` is always `<=-`. Also, you're using the wrong variable in `numStarsString`.

```
while numStars > -1:
    numStars = float(input("Enter rating for featured movie: "))
    if numStars > -1:
        numPatrons+= 1
        totalStars+=numStars
```

This loop should work.